# Google Analytics vs Quantcast

Tags: google-analytics

Is it necessary to have both GA and Quantcast in your website? I'm seeing a lot of websites use both of them but what's the point of using both of them when either one does the same thing? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is it necessary to have both GA and Quantcast in your website?**

No it is not necessary.

You may check out how they differ in this **[article](http://www.ehow.com/info_12198233_quantcast-differs-google-analytics.html)**.

> **Non-Quantified Data**
>
> Quantcast offers a separate service for those who do not participate
> in the program to track quantified data. The program for
> non-quantified data provides public statistics for millions of Web
> properties. Users of the Quantcast site use the search engine on the
> main page to look up the name of any website. Each website has its own
> stats page. A website with a small number of visitors will not
> necessarily display results due to insufficient data. **Google Analytics
> does not provide non-quantified data. You must use the tracking code
> to use Analytics, and your statistics are not open to the public.**
>
> **Methods**
>
> Google Analytics uses cookies to track visitors. Quantcast uses
> cookies and a separate people-based estimate called "cookie-corrected
> audience data." This estimate is different from both Analytics and
> Quantcast cookie-based statistics. The number of visitors tends to be
> lower for people-based estimates. Statistical measures, such as the
> number of overall visits and average pages viewed, tend to increase.

---

> **what's the point of using both of them when either one does the same
> thing?**

You may find the answer to this **[Why should I use Quantcast, Alexa or Compete, when I have Google Analytics](http://www.quora.com/Why-should-I-use-Quantcast-Alexa-or-Compete-when-I-have-Google-Analytics-in-place)**

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not necessary, but do keep in mind that Google Analytics and Quantcast are doing two different things.

Google Analytics focusses on telling you how people use your website. This includes things like referral pages and keywords, entry and exit pages, page views, and click patterns. Google Analytics tells you about the page views of your website.

Quantcast focuses on telling you the nature of your website's audience. This includes things like the users' demographics and psychographics, other sites your users tend to visits, what businesses and industries they represent, and cross platform (online, mobile, and app) engagement and retention. Quantcast tells you about the page *viewers* of your website (also referred to as your website's audience).

In many ways, Google Analytics and Quantcast Measure are very complementary services.

*Disclaimer - I work at Quantcast*

Answer (score 0):

I am using both of them and what is mentioned about quantcast is right that it has a diffferent look at traffic ..in fact at one point I was worried that it may not be appropriate to use 2 codes to measure the same traffic but I think they work fine

Comment: I would say it is necessary to check all datasources available, i.e: already mentioned quantcast, http://www.similarweb.com/ and http://www.alexarank2traffic.com/